# C++ Resource Manager base for game application

Tags: c++, performance, game

I'm writing a Resource Manager for my small but scalable future project.
The main target of this is to get best speed of access, be flexible and avoid memory leaks.

**Enumerations**

```
enum class ResourceType {
    None = 0,

    Script,
    Texture,
    Mesh,
    Shader,
    Sound,
};

enum ResourceDictionary : uint64_t {
    // Sound

    R_Sound_Click1,
    R_Sound_Click2,
    R_Sound_Click3,

    // Mesh

    R_Mesh_Monster1,
    R_Mesh_Monster2,
    R_Mesh_Monster3,

    // Shader

    R_Shader_Vertex1,
    R_Shader_Vertex2,

    // ...
};
```

**Resource base**

```
class Resource {
    ResourceType m_Type = ResourceType::None;
    std::string m_Name = "Empty";
    std::filesystem::path m_Path;

protected:
    bool m_Loaded = false;

public:
    Resource() = default;

    Resource(ResourceType type, const std::string_view name, const std::filesystem::path& path) : m_Type(type), m_Name(name), m_Path(path) {

    }

    virtual ~Resource() = default;

public:
    virtual bool Load() { return false; }
    virtual bool Unload() { return false; }

public:
    ResourceType GetType() const {
        return m_Type;
    }

    const std::string_view GetName() const {
        return m_Name;
    }

    const std::filesystem::path& GetPath() const {
        return m_Path;
    }

    bool GetLoaded() const {
        return m_Loaded;
    }
};

template<typename T>
concept ResourceComponent = std::derived_from<T, Resource>;
```

**Concrete Resource**

```
class Sound final : public Resource {
public:
    Sound() = default;

    Sound(const std::string_view name, const std::filesystem::path& path) : Resource(ResourceType::Sound, name, path) {

    }

    ~Sound() {
        if (m_Loaded) {
            Unload();
        }
    }

public:
    bool Load() override {
        m_Loaded = true;
        return true;
    }

    bool Unload() override {
        m_Loaded = false;
        return true;
    }
};
```

**Resource Manager**

```
class ResourceManager {
    using ResourceKey = ResourceDictionary;
    using ResourcePtr = std::unique_ptr<Resource>;
    using ResourceContainer = std::unordered_map<ResourceKey, ResourcePtr>;
    using ResourceContainerPair = std::pair<ResourceKey, const ResourcePtr&>;

    ResourceContainer m_Resources;

private:
    template<ResourceComponent T>
    constexpr ResourceType EnumResourceType() {
        if (std::is_same_v<T, Resource>)
            return ResourceType::None;
        else if (std::is_same_v<T, Sound>)
            return ResourceType::Sound;
        else if (std::is_same_v<T, Mesh>)
            return ResourceType::Mesh;
        else if (std::is_same_v<T, Shader>)
            return ResourceType::Shader;
    }

public:
    ResourceManager() = default;
    ~ResourceManager() = default;
    
public:
    template<ResourceComponent T>
    void Register(ResourceKey key, T* resource) {
        m_Resources.insert_or_assign(key, ResourcePtr(resource));
    }

    void Release(ResourceKey key) {
        if (!m_Resources.contains(key)) {
            return;
        }
        m_Resources.erase(key);
    }

    template<ResourceComponent T = Resource>
    void Release() {
        const ResourceType type = EnumResourceType<T>();

        std::erase_if(m_Resources, [this, type](const ResourceContainerPair& pair) {
            if (type == ResourceType::None || pair.second->GetType() == type) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        });
    }

    void Load(ResourceKey key) {
        const auto it = m_Resources.find(key);
        if (it != m_Resources.end()) {
            const auto& resource = it->second;

            if (resource->GetLoaded()) {
                // notify rewrite
                resource->Unload();
            }

            if (resource->Load()) {
                // notify success
            }
            else {
                // notify failure
            }
        }
    }

    template<ResourceComponent T = Resource>
    void Load() {
        const ResourceType type = EnumResourceType<T>();

        auto container_view = m_Resources | std::views::filter([type](const ResourceContainerPair& pair) {
            if (type == ResourceType::None) return true;
            return pair.second->GetType() == type;
        });

        for (const auto& [key, resource] : container_view) {
            if (resource->GetLoaded()) {
                // notify rewrite
                resource->Unload();
            }

            if (resource->Load()) {
                // notify success
            }
            else {
                // notify failure
            }
        }
    }

    void Unload(ResourceKey key) {
        const auto it = m_Resources.find(key);
        if (it != m_Resources.end()) {
            const auto& resource = it->second;

            if (resource->Unload()) {
                // notify success
            }
            else {
                // notify failure
            }
        }
    }

    template<ResourceComponent T = Resource>
    void Unload() {
        const ResourceType type = EnumResourceType<T>();

        auto container_view = m_Resources | std::views::filter([type](const ResourceContainerPair& pair) {
            if (type == ResourceType::None) return true;
            return pair.second->GetType() == type;
        });

        for (const auto& [key, resource] : container_view) {
            if (resource->Unload()) {
                // notify success
            }
            else {
                // notify failure
            }
        }
    }

public:
    template<ResourceComponent T>
    T* Get(ResourceKey key) const {
        static T null_resource;
        const auto it = m_Resources.find(key);
        if (it != m_Resources.end()) {
            return dynamic_cast<T*>(m_Resources.at(key).get());
        }
        // notify failure
        return &null_resource;
    }
};
```

**Example of usage**

```
int main() {
    ResourceManager manager;

    manager.Register(R_Sound_Click1, new Sound("Sound 0", "Sound/Sound0.wav"));
    manager.Register(R_Mesh_Monster1, new Mesh("Mesh 0", "Model/Mesh0.3d"));
    manager.Register(R_Sound_Click2, new Sound("Sound 1", "Sound/Sound1.wav"));
    manager.Register(R_Mesh_Monster2, new Mesh("Mesh 1", "Model/Mesh1.3d"));
    manager.Register(R_Sound_Click3, new Sound("Sound 2", "Sound/Sound2.wav"));
    manager.Register(R_Mesh_Monster3, new Mesh("Mesh 2", "Model/Mesh2.3d"));
    manager.Register(R_Shader_Vertex1, new Shader("Shader 1", "Shader/Shader0.3d"));

    // get concrete resource
    auto sound = manager.Get<Sound>(R_Sound_Click1);

    // load all resources
    manager.Load();

    // load concrete resource
    manager.Load(R_Shader_Vertex1);

    // release concrete resource
    manager.Release(R_Shader_Vertex1);

    // release sound resources
    manager.Release<Sound>();

    // release all resources
    manager.Release();
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the concrete resources? The shown one - the Sound - looks pretty dummy. Is it hypothetical?

Comment: @slepic All right, it is pretty dummy because just a example. In my idea each type of resource will have specialization in his own class, like a Sound / Shader / Texture or something else. Specialized class will have own handlers for actions like Load, Unload and etc.. Shader need upload in GPU, Sound in library and like so. Also this allows to make elegancy calls in C# style for templated functions.

Comment: Then please make it not an example, show your real code. we cannot review hypothetical code. That's specifically outside the scope of this site. If you don't have it yet, then please come back once you've implemented it.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Incorporating advice from an answer into the question violates the question-and-answer nature of this site.  You could post improved code as a new question, as an answer, or as a link to an external site - as described in [I improved my code based on the reviews. What next?](/help/someone-answers#help-post-body).  I have rolled back the edit, so the answers make sense again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Alternative ways to manage resources

Looking at your code, I think it's a bit complicated, not very flexible, and `ResourceManager` isn't much more than a glorified wrapper around a `std::unordered_map<Key, std::unique_ptr<Resource>>`. Do you need a resource manager class at all? Consider that instead of having the indirection via the key, you could create resources as global variables:

```
Sound soundClick1("Sound 0", "Sound/Sound0.wav");
Mesh meshMonster1("Mesh 0", "Model/Mesh0.3d");
…
```

You can create a header file that exports these global variables so they can be used in other source files as well.

The only advantage I currently see is that you can (un)load groups of resources in one go. You could create an array or vector of pointers to resources if you need to group them:

```
std::vector<Resource*> sounds = {&soundClick1, &soundClick2, …};
```

And for example load all resources in one go with:

```
std::ranges::for_each(sounds, [](auto& sound){ sound.Load(); });
```

While that's a bit more manual work, it is also more flexible: you can group resources however you like now, and are not confined to whatever grouping the resource manager supports. This way for example you can unload all sounds used by a game level, but not those used for the UI.

Another issue is that you still have to manually add entries to `enum ResourceDictionary` and construct resource objects. Consider making your resource manager more data driven, so it can manage resources without hardcoding anything. What if you could write this?

```
ResourceManager manager;
manager.Register("resources.txt");
Sound& soundClick1 = manager.Get<Sound>("Sound 0");
```

## Avoid passing raw pointers

It's good that you use `std::unique_ptr` to store resources, but if you want to add a resource using `Register()`, also use a `std::unique_ptr` to pass the resources. This avoids the possibility of bugs like:

```
auto soundClick1 = new Sound("Sound 0", "Sound/Sound0.wav");
manager.register(R_Sound_Click1, soundClick1);
manager.register(R_Sound_Click2, soundClick1);
```

You can change `Register()` like so:

```
template<ResourceComponent T>
void Register(ResourceKey key, ResourcePtr&& resource) {
    m_Resources.insert_or_assign(key, std::move(resource));
}
```

And call it like so:

```
manager.Register(R_Sound_Click1, std::make_unique<Sound>("Sound 0", "Sound/Sound0.wav"));
```

Or you can make it even more convenient by having `Register()` construct the resource itself:

```
template<ResourceComponent T, typename... Args>
void Register(ResourceKey key, Args&&... args) {
    m_Resources.insert_or_assign(key, std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<Args>(args)...));
}
```

And then call it like so:

```
manager.Register<Sound>(R_Sound_Click1, "Sound 0", "Sound/Sound0.wav");
```

## Make one map per resource type

Instead of having one big `std::unordered_map` storing pointers to base class, consider having multiple maps, one per resource type. This way you can store concrete types in each map. There are several ways to do this. If you already know the exact set of types you are going to support, you can make a `std::tuple`:

```
template<typename T>
using ResourceContainer = std::unordered_map<ResourceKey, T>;

std::tuple<
    ResourceContainer<Sound>,
    ResourceContainer<Mesh>,
    ResourceContainer<Shader>
> m_Resources;
…
template<ResourceComponent T, typename... Args>
void Register(ResourceKey key, Args&&... args) {
    std::get<ResourceContainer<T>>(m_Resources).try_emplace(key, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
…
template<ResourceComponent T>
T& Get(ResourceKey key) const {
    return std::get<ResourceContainer<T>>(m_Resources).at(key);
}
```

If you don't mind having `ResourceManager` be a singleton, you can simplify things by making an `inline static` template member variable:

```
template<typename T>
using ResourceContainer = std::unordered_map<ResourceKey, T>;

template<typename T>
inline static ResourceContainer<T> m_Resources;
…
template<ResourceComponent T, typename... Args>
void Register(ResourceKey key, Args&&... args) {
    m_Resources<T>.try_emplace(key, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
}
…
template<ResourceComponent T>
T& Get(ResourceKey key) const {
    return m_Resources<T>.at(key);
}
```

Note how we didn't have to make `m_Resources` a tuple, and we didn't specify in any way which types it should support. So you can add new resource types without having to modify `ResourceManager`, the drawback is that it only works if `m_Resources` is a `static` member variable, so you can't have two different instances of a `ResourceManager` manager different sets of resources.

Comment: Thank you for constructive review! Idea with stack storage have potential and self pluses, at least for fast memory access, but support this code will be very uncomfortable.
About key as string or c-string - after several tests i get that hashing of string takes too much time and it makes slower insert / find, sometimes in multiply times, this is why was been choosed so dirtly way with dictionary. Maybe it is all paranoid and in production will be not so critical, as i see string key used in many projects and it is works fine. 
Good tips, will improve code. With best regards.